# How do you update the presentation graphics of a custom flowchart block?

Tags: anylogic

I have a set of flowchart blocks that I converted to a custom block (agent type: PackLine).  After getting the logic to run properly, I inserted the custom block (agent: packLine) into my flowchart in the main window and configured all the parameters.  Once it worked right, I added presentation graphics (a rectangle that changes color based on some booleans) to the custom flowchart block's agent type (PackLine).

If I insert a new custom flowchart block, the graphics come with it, but the block inserted before I added the graphics doesn't show the rectangle.

How do I get the new presentation graphics into the main window where the existing agent is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a common issue that has a simple solution, luckily:

1. Select the block that you inserted before (i.e. not the PackLine agent type but the instance you dragged in before adding the rectangle)
2. In the properties, there is a button near the bottom named "Show Presentation", see below. (it won't be grayed out in your case)

[image]